# Asking about Flutter UI

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout

I have one question regarding Flutter UI. You guys know what this is called in flutter at "Nutrition Fact" part as my picture shown below? The keyword or package that I can search regarding that part. Hope u guys can help me.

[Image Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgcUn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called `Bottom Sheet`.
There are so many dart packages but any one of two can be use for your example.

**First :** [solid_bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/solid_bottom_sheet)

**Second :** [modal_bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a rounded container with a row widget. Row widget has 2 children: `Text("Nutritional Fact")` and `IconButton`. `MainAxisAlignment` of row is set to `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`.IconButton's `onpressed` parameter might show a `BottomModalSheet` to display the fact.

Comment: Glad to help :)